# When and how I will be paid in iTunes Connect Developer account?

Tags: app-store-connect, apple-store

For some months, I have on my account almost **16$**, but I am not paid yet.

- What should I do to receive those money from Apple?
- What is the payment schedule?
- How do I get paid by Apple for App sales?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iTunes Connect, under Agreements, Tax, and Banking, you can add your bank account. Apple will then pay the money into the account when it reaches a certain amount.

Comment: What is certain amount?;) I have 13$;)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I'm fairly certain that is too low. I believe I have seen the number $150, but I've certainly received much lower amounts than that. How long have you had that amount in your account? It could be that they process payments after a long time has passed without getting above the limit as well.

Comment: 2months:) but it still increases... Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 6):

This is the direct response from Apple to me:

> Payments are made **within 45 days of the last day of the fiscal month**. To receive payment, you must have completed all documentation, including any required banking and tax information, as well as meeting the minimum payment threshold.
>
> If your bank and bank account currency is listed in the table provided in the iTunes Connect Payments and Financial Reports FAQ's labeled *WHEN WILL I BE PAID*, you must exceed a **minimum payment threshold of $10 USD**.
>
> All other bank countries and bank account currencies must exceed a **minimum payment threshold of $150 USD**. Earnings that do not meet the minimum payment threshold will be carried over month-to-month until the minimum is met.

Answer (score 3):

You can see when any particular payment will be made by logging in to iTunesConnect and going to Payments and Financial Reports. Any payment due to be made will be in the top right, alongside the date it will be made. You may need to go back a month as for some reason ITC only shows the current month, which never seems to have any data in it.

Payments cover the period displayed in Apple's fiscal calendar https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=fiscalcalendar